# Is it possible to load Dynamic feature from a library in android?

Tags: android, gradle, android-library, google-play-core, dynamic-delivery

Can i load a dynamic function from a jitpack library ?
My use case is:

I developed an android app (30MB due to product requirement) which i want to share with third party vendors. i cannot share my code with them because of privacy. cannot convert this code into jitpack lib because it will directly increase vendor's app size.

All i want to do is create a smaller jitpack library which will load this app as a dynamic module.
so that i can share that library with third party vendor.

Let me know if its possible or there is any better way to do this

tried creating jitpack library with on-demand dynamic module inside it. But this module is not available for vendor's app.